# Why is the movie named "Knight of Cups"?

Tags: title, knight-of-cups

The Christian Bale movie [*Knight of Cups* (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_of_Cups_(film)) is a drama movie. What is the significance of the movie name as  Knight of Cups?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Knight of Cups is a tarot card that often appears as an invitation or a messenger of someone with an emotional benefit. It can also depict arrival of someone. However, when it is upside down, it represents an event or situation which was appealing at first, but turns out something very different and disappointing.

From [Biddy Tarot](https://www.biddytarot.com/tarot-card-meanings/minor-arcana/suit-of-cups/knight-of-cups/),

> The Knight of Cups reversed indicates a situation which was initially incredibly appealing, romantic and exciting but which later turns out to be something very different, and one walks away feeling quite disappointed. It is as though you are wearing the rose-coloured glasses, or going through the honeymoon period, only to come out realising that the situation is quite different to what you thought.

This card is pretty much similar to Rick's life (played by Christian Bale) and the movie poster shows Rick upside down. Haunted by the death of his brother and serious condition of another, he comes across many women during his journey (arrival of someone with emotional benefit) and gets disappointed all the time. And in the end, he finally learns the truth just like the knight in that tarot card.

From [Plugged-in movie review](https://www.pluggedin.com/movie-reviews/knight-of-cups/),

> One woman, a stripper who says she changes her “reality” every evening, seems closely associated with Hinduism: They vacation at Caesars Palace in Las Vegas, where a Hindu shrine appears in the background. We also see a man playfully slap a thin stone onto his brow, imitating the Hindu “third eye.” Another woman, calm and peaceful, is shown doing yogic exercises in front of a statue of the Buddha. She rejects Rick’s advances, saying, “I don’t want to wreak havoc in men’s lives anymore”—an echo of the Buddhist concept of peaceful, emotionless Nirvana. Rick visits a Zen garden with yet another woman and visits with a man who apparently played at being an Eastern monk for a while.
>
> Rick also visits a museum filled with Christian artwork. And his father is shown praying, petitioning God for forgiveness. Quotations from the Bible and Christian prayers echo throughout the movie. And before the film ends, **we meet a priest who says that suffering is a gift from God, not a curse—that it helps bind us closer to Him.**

Answer (score 3):

The whole film has a Tarot theme; the Knight of Cups is a Tarot card signifying folly and search, thereby referencing the protagonist's behaviour in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

[According to We Are Movie Geeks](http://www.wearemoviegeeks.com/2016/01/christian-bale-is-on-a-quest-in-knight-of-cups-poster/):

> the title refers to the Tarot card depicting a romantic adventurer guided by his emotions